# Poincaré conjecture for positively curved Thurston geometries

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology, curvature

The passages below are from [Terence Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/04/01/285g-lecture-2-the-ricci-flow-approach-to-the-poincare-conjecture/). I don't know how to get Corollary 1 from Exercises 2 and 3. I understand that the spherical space form (as the metric) is invariant under $SO(n)$, where $n$ is one plus the dimension of the manifold.

> **Exercise 2**. Let $M$, $M'$ be connected manifolds of the same dimension.
>
> 1. Show that $M\#M'$ is compact if and only if $M$ and $M'$ are both compact.
> 2. Show that $M\#M'$ is orientable if and only if $M$ and $M'$ are both orientable.
> 3. Show that $M\#M'$ is simply connected if and only if $M$ and $M'$ are both simply connected.
>
> The sphere also plays a special role, as the identity for the connected sum operation:
>
> **Exercise 3**. Let $M$ be a connected manifold, and let $S$ be a sphere of the same dimension. Show that $M\#S$ (or $S\#M$) is homeomorphic to $M$. $\lozenge$

---

> Recall that of the spherical space forms and $S^2$-bundles over $S^1$ mentioned above, the sphere $S^3$ was the only one which was simply connected. From Exercises 2 and 3 we thus have
>
> > **Corollary 1**. (Poincaré conjecture for positively curved Thurston geometries) Let $M$ be a simply connected 3-manifold which is the connected sum of finitely many spherical space forms and $S^2$-bundles over $S^1$. Then $M$ is homeomorphic to the sphere $S^3$.

([pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSNaZ.png), [pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoO1e.png))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Killing-Hopf, the only simply-connected spherical space form in dimension $3$ is $S^3$ itself. For a bundle $S^2 \to E \to S^1$, the long exact sequence in homotopy gives a surjection $\pi_1(E) \to \mathbb{Z}$. In particular, $\pi_1(E)\not= 1$. By Exercise 2(c), the manifold $M$ in the corollary must be a connected sum of copies of $S^3$, and thus (by Exercise 3 or a direct argument) must be $S^3$ itself.

Comment: what is $E$ ? I am not familiar with homotopy theory, why there is a exact sequence ?

Comment: $E$ is the (total space of the) bundle in question. A bundle with total space $E$, base space $B$, and fiber $F$ is usually written as $F \to E \to B$. (When convenient, the last map is sometimes written vertically.) A general fibration induces a long exact sequence in homotopy.

Comment: Whether you are proving the $S^2$-bundles over  $S^1$ is not simply connected ?Besides, how to know  $\pi_1(E) \to \mathbb{Z}$ is surjective ?

Comment: @lanse7pty: The hypothesis of the corollary is that $E$ is simply-connected, and surjectivity follows immediately from the long exact sequence.